# dijkstra algorithm return path of vertices

Tags: c++, algorithm, logic, dijkstra

I have an assignment that I am doing for college that requires me to implement dijkstra algorithm in c++ for simulating a network sending packets. My dijkstra algorithm needs to be implemented so that I can return a valid path to the each node in the tree, I have this:

```
unordered_map<Vertex*, Path> computeShortestPath(Vertex *start)
{
    //holds known distances
    unordered_map<Vertex*, Path> distances;

    //underlying heap
    priority_queue<Vertex*, vector<Vertex*>, PathWeightComparer> dijkstra_queue{};

    //reset start's path weight
    start->setPathWeight(0);

    //make sure that the starting vertex is in the graph
    if (_vertices.find(start->getId()) != _vertices.end())
    {
        //push on starting vertex
        dijkstra_queue.push(_vertices.at(start->getId()));



    while (dijkstra_queue.size() > 0)
        {

            Vertex *t = dijkstra_queue.top();

            dijkstra_queue.pop();
            distances[t];

            unordered_map<Vertex*, int> edges = t->getEdges();


            for (auto it = edges.begin(); it != edges.end(); ++it)
            {

                int newDistance = (it->second + distances[t].getPathWeight());


                if (newDistance < distances[it->first].getPathWeight() || (distances[it->first].getPathWeight() == 0 ))
                {

                    queue<Vertex*>verts = distances[t].getVertices();

                    verts.push(it->first);

                    distances[it->first].setVertices(verts);

                    distances[it->first].setPathWeight(newDistance);


                    dijkstra_queue.push(it->first);
                }
            }

        }

    }


    return distances;
}
```

With sample data given to me by an instructor:

Vertices: {v1, v2, v3}, Links(one way): { (v1,v2,5), (v1,v3,10), (v2,v3,4) }

Now when I call this function one vertex 1 I should receive an unordered map in memory as follows:

Vertex:Path

```
1:{Null} (indicating this is source node)
2:{v2}
3:{v2,v3}
```

However on vertex 3 I receive:

```
3:{v3,v2,v3}
```

I've been working on the overall project for a while and this is the last little issue I need to work out for the assignment to be completed. Any help is appreciated.

Everything else has been tested and working 100% I need to just spot my logic flaw, Thanks.

Comment: Either step through your code line by line using a debugger or print statements, or isolate your problem to a smaller chunk of code and then ask here.

Comment: Your question contains quite a lot while it also lacks crucial parts. For example, it lacks how `PathWeightComparer` is defined and whether `Path::setPathWeight()` may affect the result of this comparer. Also, your example missing is failing. One thing I consider is a red flag is the use of `std::priority_queue`: you need to change the distance of enqueued nodes which `std::priority_queue` cannot do. Without that ability you can't implement the Dijkstra algorithm correctly (note that correct implementation requires a correct run-time complexity).